# display multiple time of same div tag using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want display different text with same div tag using for loop. means if i have three text's i will display each text with same div tag separately. i have three arrays. 1st two arrays contains x and y cooridantes based on these text will be displayed on div tag separately. following is my code.

```
  var i=1;
  for(var l=0;l<5;l++){
      $("#dimg1").attr('id','dimg'+i)
      $("#test").attr('id','test'+i)

        var st1=new Array();
        var st2=new Array();
        var st3=new Array();           

        st1=[120,150,190,250];
        st2=[130,170,220,280];
        st3=[Text1,Text2,Text3,Text4];
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#dimg1").hover(function(){     
           i++;

           for(var j=0;j<3;j++)
           {
              var X=st1[j];      
              var Y=st2[j];
              var txt=st3[j];      

              var test = $("<span class='test'+j></span>");

              test.html(txt);
              $(this).append(test.offset({left:X,top:Y}));
              //alert(i);
            }

         }, function(){
              $(".test").remove();
         }
      );

       });
   }
```

u also see output in

```
<div id="dimg1" class="dimg1" style=" border-color: #36C; border-style: dotted; width: 300px; height: 300px"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you plz post jsfiddle link?

Comment: see the out put here http://i.stack.imgur.com/jFKpj.png

Comment: do you even have a clue what you want and what your code does?

Comment: When will for(var l=0;l<5;l++){..} executed? I think you misplaced document.ready()

Comment: @user2215185 : You better post your html code too. Or share a jsfiddle link.

Comment: my project is online social network like facebook. in facebook we may tag the photo. so when ever we place the mouse over the image related text will be displayed like names,places etc., here also i want implement that. so i successfully tagged the photo but unable to display the text after retrieving

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pz9hB/2/ please visit the code here. actually here i am writing code only for display same div tag. but i want display separately like above output example. @slacker

Comment: @user2215185 : You mean, you want # more similar divisions generated below the original division with those messages separately?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make 4 divisions ,3 hidden.

Then you can load text and hide them appropriately.

[Here is what I come up with](http://jsfiddle.net/yNS9s/)

**Script**

```
 $("#myimg1").hover(function(){

      var x1=["50","100","150","200"];
      var y1=["50","100","150","200"];
      var txt1=["Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4"];
      var i=0;

      for(var i=1;i<4;i++)
      {
          var X=x1[i-1];
          var Y=y1[i-1];
          var txt=txt1[i-1];
          var test = $("<span class='test'></span>");
          test.html(txt);

          $("#myimg"+i).append(test.offset({left:X,top:Y}));
      }

$('.myimgcls').show();
 }, function() {

     $('.test').remove();
$('.myimgcls').not('.firstimg').hide();     
 });
```

**CSS:**

```
.myimgcls {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px dashed #f30;
    position:relative;
}

.test {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div id="myimg1" class='myimgcls firstimg'></div>
<div id="myimg2" class='myimgcls' style="display:none"></div>
<div id="myimg3" class='myimgcls' style="display:none"></div>
<div id="myimg4" class='myimgcls' style="display:none"></div>
```